# Schedule query on bigquery - cant create schedule query with the table get external data from googlesheet

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've create the bigquery table with the name 'table_a', which was get data from google sheet. I cant you this table directly to use on other service, and I want to create schedule query to create new table

```
select * from table_a => table_b
```

but there was some problem when I scheduled this query:

> Error code 3 : Invalid value: table_a is not allowed for this operation because it is currently a EXTERNAL.

I need your help on this, how can I create a table_b from table_a.

Many thanks

Comment: I tried to replicate this, but I didn't have any issues while scheduling a query with a Google Sheets external table. It'll be helpful if you could specify the steps that you did to try scheduling your query.

Comment: External table cannot be destination table and the error message matches what you provided. Guess you mixed up source and destination table.